# Using triple integrals to find volume

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> Find the volume of the solid defined by the inequalities
>
> $0 \le z \le y \le x \le 1$.

I know I have to use triple integrals to solve this problem, but I am pretty confused as to how I should approach it. I am having trouble figuring out what the limits of integration are for $x$,$y$, and $z$ given the above inequality.

Comment: Isn't this a cube with sides just less than1?

Comment: Hint: the region in the $xy$ plane bounded by $y=0, y=x, x=1$ is the "floor" of the solid, and is also the region of projection. The "roof" is the plane $z=y$.

Answer (score 1):

If you were to do this with integrals, where $S = \{ (x,y,z) : 0 \le z \le y \le x \le 1 \}$ your integral limits would be 
$$
\text{Volume} 
= \iiint_S dV
= \int_0 ^1 \int_0 ^x \int_0 ^y dz dy dx
= \frac{1}{6}
$$